# Boolean Modifier Trouble - Yes.... The Anvil

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am following a tutorial by the Blender Guru on how to make an anvil and everything was going well until I came to use the Boolean tool. When I use it - I do see a cut out in the mesh, however when I apply it - nothing happens. I have tried using the Bool Tool (pic 2) and it creates the cut out in the mesh but does not delete the faces in the shape of the cylinder in the anvil.

[image: Pic One]

[image: Pic Two]

I have seen solutions for this in earlier versions of blender Choosing Carve instead of Bmesh but there does not seem to be that option in 2.81

Comment: No.. not the anvil.. lol.

Comment: A default anvil.

Comment: Maybe check that the cylinder has it's scale applied?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are not enough loopcuts on your anvil to hold the cut.

Try to place loopcuts where the cut should occur.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the cylinder a few degrees around the zed axis to fix it.